# Why is Leslie's mom cool with Parker?

Tags: plot-explanation, parker

When Parker shows up at Leslie's house all bloody after his fight with the hit man, why is Leslie's mom cool with him being there? Do they know each other? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leslie's Mom, Ascension, used to own a beauty salon and is now retired. Leslie has now moved back in with her and is in effect mooching off her. Ascension did not approve of Leslie's ex (who was a con) and thinks that she should find a man for herself who will take care of her and treat her right. She believes that Parker fits the description and at one point states, "This is a real man", or words to that effect.

Comment: I inferred that from their interactions, but how did Parker arrive at the house and interact with Ascension to get to a point where she was ok with a man breaking into her house, while all bloody, and not be upset?

Comment: @DustinDavis It's been a while since I saw it. But IIRC, Leslie is the one who notices him first. The fact that her daughter knows a/the guy (and is covering for him) perhaps changed the situation for her.

Comment: @coleopterit that makes sense, maybe there was no interaction before but when she saw Leslie with him and the fact that the dog wasn't barking made her be cool about it. I accept that as an answer.